# Probability basics question

Tags: probability

There are n urns of which the k-th contains k − 1 red balls and n − k black balls. You pick an urn at random and remove two balls at random without replacement. Find the probability that: the second ball is red.

I know that if we want to calculate the probability that the first ball is either red or black we get a probability equal to 1/2.
But what do we do in the case second is red? 
Is it correct to say P(C2=R)=P(C1=B/C2=B)+P(C1=R/C2=B)??

Comment: You surely aren't writing what you mean to say.  The right-hand of your equation is equal to $1$ since the first ball is surely black or red.  I think you mean $$P(C_2=R)=P(C_2=R|C_1=B)\cdot P(C_1=B)+P(C_2=R|C_1=R)\cdot P(C_1=R)$$

Answer (score 2):

Stop and think about the question before flinging equations at it.  The problem is symmetric in black and red.  For every urn with $b$ black balls and $r$ red balls, there is an urn with $b$ red balls and $r$ black balls.  Therefore, the probability that the second ball is red must, by symmetry, be equal to the probability that the second ball is black.

So, they are both equal to ...

Answer (score 0):

P( First Ball is Red) $= \frac{1}{n}\frac{k-1}{n-1}\tag 1$

P( First Ball is Black) $= \frac{1}{n}\frac{n-k}{n-1}\tag 2$

P( Second Ball is Red/ First Ball is Red) = $\frac{k-2}{n-2}\tag 3$

P( Second Ball is Red/ First Ball is Black) = $\frac{k-1}{n-2}\tag 4$

Thus P(Second ball is Red) = (3).(1) + (4).(2)

$$\frac{k-1}{n(n-1)}\frac{k-2}{n-2}+\frac{k-1}{n-2}\frac{n-k}{n(n-1)}$$

$$ =\frac{k(n-2)+2-n}{n(n-1)(n-2)} = \frac{(k-1)}{n(n-1)}$$

Probability that the second ball is red = $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k-1)}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{2}$